# Run a function after a page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

Alright guys, so I have a page that uses php functions with jquery functions.

The jQuery functions or simple confirmation boxes and dialog boxes. So what I need now is when an user clicks a button, I need to show a confirmation box.
Then when the user accepts, I run a php function that ends with a page refresh then I want to show a dialog box to show it has been done.

But now what happens is that, the confirmation boxes appears. When users accepts, the dialog box starts to show but right then, the page refreshes...

Here is the php function thats gets called when users clicks ok from the confirmation box:

```
function resetText()
{
    $url = curPageURL();
    ?>
    location.href='<?php echo"$url"; ?>'
    message();
    <?php
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please post your entire code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be trying to use web technologies in a way they weren't built to be used. The web is built on a client-server model; in your case, php *only* runs on the server, and javascript (and jQuery) *only* runs on the user's web browser. In order to call php from javascript, you'll have to do so in the form of a new web request.

You'll want to move whatever it is you wanted to do in php to a different url endpoint that you can call, say, /callback.php, which after some thought returns something like:

```
{ 'myUrl': 'http://stackoverflow.com' }
```

Then, your jQuery will look something like:

```
$('#myButton').click(function()
{
    if (confirm('My confirmation message'))
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/callback.php',
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert('You\'re about to go to ' + result.myUrl);
                window.location.href = result.myUrl;
            },
            error: function(request)
            {
                // handle somehow
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I realize now that I interpreted what you wanted backwards. For what you want, you'll instead probably want to add a querystring param to the page the user ends up on, and if the param is there, add a <script> tag with the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Clint is right - PHP is server-side, so you'd have to run the function via an ajax call.

Still though, if that can work for you and if you want to see the popup box on a refresh, you could set a session variable before the refresh is performed then do something like:

```
$(document).onReady(function(){
      if (isset(that session var)){ show that popup, remove session var }
});
```